# wordpress .htaccess file has automatically modified

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

i am using Wordpress. 
added the code in .htaccess file.
By the way, is modified automatically 
Changes are made automatically.  and added code was deleted.again again
how can I do that? 
please help me

Comment: We're going to need more information. What code are you trying to add to `.htaccess`? There is a bit of default WordPress code, but that shouldn't affect anything you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any plugins that affect the .htaccess file , if you are not aware than try to deactivate your plugins one by one , and check your .htaccess file if that is still deleted than let me know i will find another solutions.